# How to make pop up only appear on Homepage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have an age-verification pop up that appears once on first visit to site. When age has been verified, the pop up disappears. How do I make this pop up appear only on the homepage but not on any others? Do I need to add something to my script below?

Any help much appreciated.

JS below:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

<script> jQuery(document).ready(function($){
           
 
if (sessionStorage.getItem('advertOnce') !== 'true') {
//Show Box on Start-Up
  $('.box').show();
  $('.overlay-verify').show();
}else{
  $('.box').hide();
  $('.overlay-verify').hide();
}
 
//Enter Button
$('#refresh-page').on('click',function(){
$('.box').hide();
$('.overlay-verify').hide();
sessionStorage.setItem('advertOnce','true');
});

//Exit Button
$('#reset-session').on('click',function(){
$('.box').show();
sessionStorage.setItem('advertOnce','');
});
});
    
</script>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600,900,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<main>
  <article class="box">
    <div class="box-left">
      <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ef08aa918c34c5e1ee24d37/t/5efc646a19c9962072e60679/1593599082426/SBR_centered+copy+-+white.png">
    </div>
    <div class="box-right">
      <h3>Welcome</h3>
      <p>By clicking enter, I certify that I am over the age of 18.</p>
     
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-alpha"  id="refresh-page">ENTER</a>
     
  <span>OR</span>
     
      <a href="javascript:history.back()" class="btn btn-beta" id="reset-session">EXIT</a>
     
      <small>Always enjoy responsibily.</small>
    </div>
    </div>
  </article>
 
  <div class="overlay-verify"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `window.location.pathname` in your script, example:

```js
if (sessionStorage.getItem('advertOnce') !== 'true' && window.location.pathname == "/") {
    $('.box').show();
    $('.overlay-verify').show();
}
```

This will now only execute when on the index [/] - you can change the condition to work for another page name too: `if(window.location.pathname == "/home.html")`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a cookie that stock the age and if this cookie already exists don't execute the code and when this cookie doesn't exist execute the code